# Erro: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Alguém consegue identificar qual o erro em meu código?

Seguem as minhas *classes*:

`Program`:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        using(var db = new StudentContext()) {

            var student = new Student() {
                Name = "Kelly Soares"
            };
            var mathSubj = new Subject() {
                Name = "Mathematics"
            };
            var scienceSubj = new Subject() {
                Name = "Data Structures"
            };

            student.Subjects.Add(mathSubj);
            student.Subjects.Add(scienceSubj);

            db.Students.Add(student);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

`Student`:

```
public class Student {
    public int StudentId {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Name {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual List Subjects {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

`Subject`:

```
public class Subject {

    public int SubjectId {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Student Students {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

`StudentContext`:

```
public class StudentContext: DbContext {
    public StudentContext(): base(@"Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=tempdb; Integrated Security=true")     {

    }
    public DbSet < Student > Students {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DbSet < Subject > Subjects {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Em qual linha ocorre o erro?

Comment: É bem provável que tu não esteja usando a versão 6 do `ef`e as `Lists` não estejam sendo inicializadas sozinhas...

Comment: Bruno, ele está dando erro já nesta linha student.Subjects.Add(mathSubj); assim que ele tenta fazer a primeira inserção.

Comment: Você pode colocar também a Stack Trace na sua pergunta, por favor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faltou você inicializar a lista virtual no construtor da classe e definir o tipo da lista.

```
public class Student
{

    public Student()
    {
        Subjects = new List<Subject>();
    }

    public int StudentId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual List<Subject> Subjects
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ismael funcionou. Grata!